# Unable to bind docker.sock to Docker Service

Tags: docker, terraform, bind, docker-swarm

I am trying to setup a docker service (via terraform) which will run jenkins as containers. I want to bind the host VM's docker docket to the docker service. I tried two options.

1. Docker Service as command
2. Spawn docker service using terraform

While the service gets instantiated successfully, the container doesn't recognize the docker socket. I can see the `/var/run/docker.sock` file inside the container but docker command wont work.

The code block for your reference.

DOCKER SERVICE COMMAND

```
docker service  create --name aws --mount=type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

TERRAFORM MAIN TF FILE

```
resource "docker_service" "jenkins_service" {
  name = var.project_name
  task_spec {
    container_spec {
      image = docker_image.jenkins_image.name
      mounts {
        source = var.jenkins_volume
        target = "/var/jenkins_home"
        type   = "bind"
      }
      mounts {
        source = "/var/run/docker.sock"
        target = "/var/run/docker.sock"
        type   = "bind"
      }
    }
    networks = ["${docker_network.jenkins_network.name}"]
  }

  endpoint_spec {
    ports {
      target_port    = "8080"
      published_port = var.web_interface_port
      publish_mode   = "ingress"
      name           = "WEB_INTERFACE"
    }
    ports {
      target_port    = "50000"
      published_port = var.api_interface_port
      publish_mode   = "ingress"
      name           = "API_INTERFACE"
    }
  }
}
```

**Error Message**

> bash-4.2$ docker exec  -u 0 -it 9bc2a468174a bash
>   root@9bc2a468174a:/# docker
>   bash: docker: command not found
>   root@9bc2a468174a:/# ls -ltr /var/run/docker.sock
>   srwxrwxrwx. 1 root 167 0 Sep 24 11:02 /var/run/docker.sock

**Docker Version**

> -bash-4.2$ docker version
>   Client:
>    Version:           18.09.8
>    API version:       1.39
>    Go version:        go1.10.8
>    Git commit:        0dd43dd87f
>    Built:             Wed Jul 17 17:40:31 2019
>    OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
>    Experimental:      false
>
> Server: Docker Engine - Community
>    Engine:
>     Version:          18.09.8
>     API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
>     Go version:       go1.10.8
>     Git commit:       0dd43dd
>     Built:            Wed Jul 17 17:10:42 2019
>     OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
>     Experimental:     false

Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Regards
Senthil Nathan M

Comment: If you're seeing the `docker.sock` special file then the bind-mount is working correctly.  As @ShashankV says in their answer, and as described in the linked question, you don't have a `docker` binary inside the container, which is the other part necessary for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash: docker: command not found`.

You don't have docker client installed in your container. Mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` from host inside the container just makes the container's docker client talk to host's docker daemon. You still need to install at least the docker client in your container.